# I'm wanting to duplicate but maintain state separately for each component. Do I need to create each function for each component separately instead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'm wanting to duplicate but maintain state separately for each component. Do I need to create each function for each component separately instead? Right now if you look at the code there's only one Player component that's being used multiple times but currently the code is using the same state, thus when updating the state with the onClick function updates all the Player components.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Player from './Player'

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    players: 2,
    score: 0,
  }
  resetBoard = () => {
    this.setState({ players: 2, score: 0 })
  }

  updateScoreFive = () => {
    return this.setState({ score: this.state.score + 5 })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Player
          key={1}
          five={this.updateScoreFive}
          score={this.state.score}
          name={this.state.players <= 2 ? 'Team One' : 'Player One'}
        />
        <Player
          key={2}
          score={this.state.score}
          name={this.state.players <= 2 ? 'Team Two' : 'Player Two'}
        />

        <button onClick={this.resetBoard}>Reset Board</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Player component should manage its own state. There's no way to differentiate scores between them because they're both being passed the same value `this.state.score`, unless you pass them different values from the state which means having different keys for each player inside the state and handling them accordingly.

On a side note, when you need to reference your current state inside setState (as you did in your updateScoreFive function) it's better to pass it a function instead of an object to avoid issues due to the async nature of setState:

```
this.setState( prevState => ({ score: prevState.score + 5 }))
```

This way you make sure you always get the updated value inside your setState function.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `score` an object and save the score of different players against different keys of that object:

```
state = {
    players: 2,
    score: {},
}
```

Now modify your `updateScoreFive` method to take an player argument, that way it knows which player's score is going to be updated:

```
// it takes an argument `player` and returns a function
// in which it updates the score state against the key `player` 
updateScoreFive = (player) => () => {
  this.setState({
    score: {
      ...this.state.score,
      [player]: (this.state.score[player] || 0) + 5
    }
  })
}
```

Now render your components:

```
// save it's score in score[1]
<Player
  key={1}
  five={this.updateScoreFive(1)}
  score={this.state.score[1] || 0}
  name={this.state.players <= 2 ? 'Team One' : 'Player One'}
/>
// save it's score in score[2]
<Player
  key={2}
  five={this.updateScoreFive(2)}
  score={this.state.score[2] || 0}
  name={this.state.players <= 2 ? 'Team Two' : 'Player Two'}
/>
```

Your `resetBoard` changes too:

```
resetBoard = () => {
    this.setState({ players: 2, score: {} })
}
```